# Any mistakes with my code? Display always go to left. I cannot fix it

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

Here is the link

https://github.com/noel020395/projectno1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuEVh.jpg)

I m stuck here, unable to fix the layout issue. Any one could guide me the errors?

Comment: All the methods mentioned, I try already, but still not working? The display still go to left?

Answer (score 1):

body {width : 100 %} or  body { margin-left :}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your content isn't 100% width, so naturally, it will appear to align left. if you want a more centred look, specify a `max-width` and `margin:auto`.

Something like this

```
section {
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put this div to your every car item

```
 <div class="col-4 d-flex align-items-center bg-info justify-content-center flex-column">
                <a href="target_blank"><img src="https://baaylimo.sg/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/voxy-600x380.jpg"
                        width="300px" /></a>
                <p>Toyota </p>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can use @media screen on body 2 times, 1 width is set to 50% and another one is 100%.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 100%){
body{width: 100%;}}
```